# Suggestion for websites which list open PhD positions in Mathematics in France, UK, Netherlands, Denmark only

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, europe, website

I am a student of an Asian country who completed the 2nd year of masters last year  and I am applying for PhD positions in Pure Mathematics in Europe.

I know about [this scholarship database website](https://scholarshipdb.net/scholarship-scholarships/Program-Undergraduate) which list open positions for PhDs, but I don't think that the list is complete by any means.

Can you please let me know of some websites that have a list of open PhD positions in Pure Mathematics in Europe?

Comment: Europe is a continent and not a country. A lot of these things are organized nationally.

Comment: You should identify the departments/supervisors you are interested in working with and check their websites to see if they are advertising for PhD students. There's no global system.

Comment: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/mathdept.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all open academic positions (including PhD positions) in the Netherlands will be posted to:

- [www.academictransfer.com](https://www.academictransfer.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at the European Commission database of offers

**https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/**

The filtering options are quite useful, although I would suggest you leaving them loose.

The site you listed is just crawling across this site, so better to go straight to the source of informations.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all open PhD positions (in any field) in the UK will be on [FindAPhD.com](https://www.findaphd.com/).

Comment: I don't think that's always true. The department I did my PhD in used to advertise one or two projects are year on there (usually the flashy ones with the big-name supervisor) but there were many other available projects and supervisors besides those directly advertised. Nevertheless, it's a starting point.